# Why do we use nichrome if heat is inversely proportional to resistance at constant voltage?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, electrical-resistance

Why do we use nichrome in heating appliances? I've been listening that it offers higher resistance and hence, should generate more heat; as governed by $H=i^2Rt$. But, shouldn't we be using heating appliances at constant potential difference (like 220V or whatever the mains voltage is in your region) rather than constant current? Shouldn't we be applying $H=V^2/Rt$ instead?

If so, then what is the real reason of using nichrome wires? I've been searching about this for a while and couldn't find anything satisfactory. What am I missing?

Comment: Note that your second equation for heat is ambiguous.  I assume that you mean $H=(V^2/R)t$.

Comment: One reason nichrome wire is used in resistance heaters is it has a very high melting point and retains its shape even when red hot.